# Strange error 403: "Calendar usage limits exceeded" when adding event with attendee

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps

I'm trying to test adding an event to my Google Calendar using Google API Explorer page at [Google API Explorer - calendar.event.insert](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.events.insert)

Specifying '**primary**' as the calendarId, and enabling '**OAuth 2.0**' authorization.

The request body field is as follows:

```
{
  "summary": "Another test",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2017-01-17T11:30:00+02:00"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2017-01-17T12:00:00+02:00"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "email": "some_mail@some_domain.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when clicking the '**Authorize and Execute**' button, I get the following error:

```
403

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "quotaExceeded",
    "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."
 }
}
```

If I send the same request but without the '**attendees**' part, it works every time.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I have found this article, that might put some light on this bug:
https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3363

Comment: Not related that's using service accounts your not using service accounts.

Comment: here is my solution step by step: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63715242/5212039

Answer (score 1):

API explorer dumps you into the same quota with everyone else using the api explorer as most of the quotas are project based and its the same project.

You are probably getting it because there are other people testing what you are testing at the same time.  There are also limits to what you can test with that.  I suspect it wasn't meant to be fully functional.

Also check [Calendar usage limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en) *How much have you been testing?*

> Calendar usage limits exceeded. This is the result of an API call.
>   (Don't mix this up with the message "Daily quota exceeded," which
>   points to insufficient API quota.)
>
> **Creating too many events**
>
> If a user has created more than 10,000 events in his or her calendar
>   within a short period of time, that user might lose calendar edit
>   access.

Solution: Send the requests from your own application rather then using api explorer.

What I am sending works fine.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?sendNotifications=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2017-01-17T11:30:00+02:00"
 },
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2017-01-17T11:30:00+02:00"
 },
 "attendees": [
  {
   "email": "ll@xxxx.com"
  }
 ]
}
```

Response:

200

```
- Show headers -

{


 "kind": "calendar#event",
 "etag": "\"2969293763864000\"",
 "id": "did1s0f76g79s1ht5aplhieoik",
 "status": "confirmed",
 "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=ZGlkMXMwZjc2Zzc5czFodDVhcGxoaWVvaWsgbGF1cmx5NzFAbQa",
 "created": "2017-01-17T09:54:41.000Z",
 "updated": "2017-01-17T09:54:41.932Z",
 "creator": {
  "email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
  "displayName": "Linda Lawton",
  "self": true
 },
 "organizer": {
  "email": "xxxxx@gmail.com",
  "displayName": "Linda Lawton",
  "self": true
 },
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2017-01-17T10:30:00+01:00"
 },
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2017-01-17T10:30:00+01:00"
 },
 "iCalUID": "1s0f76g79s1ht5aplhieoik@google.com",
 "sequence": 0,
 "attendees": [
  {
   "email": "ll@xxxxx",
   "responseStatus": "needsAction"
  }
 ],
 "reminders": {
  "useDefault": true
 }
}
```

Comment: The reason I'm using the explorer is because my application gets the same error. And you are wrong about the quota, since I'm using a different authorization (the quota is per user).
Also, when I remove the 'attendees' part - it works fine multiple times.

Comment: just that email? have you tested with different email addresses?

Comment: Sure. All emails fail. See my comment to the question - there might be a bug in Google API...

Comment: I just tested it and it worked for me.  adding an attended it even sent an email to my attendee notifying them of the appointment.

Comment: Is your attendee has a gmail address? Try someone in a different domain...

Comment: Please try to add some more events. As far as I see in the BUG report (link is in a comment to my question) it will fail on the second event. If this still works for you - I have no idea what can go wrong... Are you using the API explorer tool too?

Comment: I have added six so far same email same time always works

Comment: are you sure you haven't messed up your scope and are only requesting read access at somepoint?

Comment: yes using the page you linked for v3 API instead of V4 which I also checked.   I have linked both the request its building and the response it is returning.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.events.insert?calendarId=primary&_h=2&resource=%257B%250A+%2522end%2522%253A+%257B%250A++%2522dateTime%2522%253A+%25222017-01-17T11%253A30%253A00%252B02%253A00%2522%250A+%257D%252C%250A+%2522start%2522%253A+%257B%250A++%2522dateTime%2522%253A+%25222017-01-17T11%253A30%253A00%252B02%253A00%2522%250A+%257D%252C%250A+%2522attendees%2522%253A+%255B%250A++%257B%250A+++%2522email%2522%253A+%2522ll%2540xxxx.com%2522%250A++%257D%250A+%255D%250A%257D&

When I click 'execute' I get this error. :(

Comment: yes again I am using the apis explorer for v3.  It works fine there are no issues I can click the button again and again and it works.   I have tested with bad emails , good emails, non google emails.  time in the future and the exact time you are using.  What ever your problem is its not related to the API the api works fine.

Comment: calendar usage limits would explain why it works for me and not for you.

Comment: But it would not explain why I can add unlimited events without any other attendees, but not events with attendees...

Comment: depends on if you are sending the same email address and its the other persons email that is kicking out.

Comment: I've tried to authorize using a different google user - thus adding to another calebdarand now it seems to work. Might be some quota on the calendar...

Comment: The limits hit here are probably those on new events or on the number of invitations: Sending too many invitations or emails to external guests

In order to prevent spamming, Google Calendar limits the number of invitations a user can send to external guests. This limit varies depending on the action, and is usually between 100-300 guests.